# How to pass data to controller and back to the view in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angular-controller

I have the following function that adds a comma every 3 characters as you type, so for example `1000` with return `1,000`

http://plnkr.co/edit/TL8hlIxyPbwUNCbLiKgs?p=preview

But the function is specific to that input field's `ng-model`. How do I return the value of `$scope.item.price` back to the view in a way that I can reuse the function with any input field? Such as using `x` instead of `item.price` in the function.

Perhaps using `return` or maybe writing a directive, but not sure how to do that.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name='' ng-model='item.price' ng-change='addCommas(item)' />
```

JS

```
    $scope.addCommas = function(item){
        price = item.price
        if (price){
            $scope.item.price_clean = price = price.replace(/,/g, '')
            $scope.item.price = price.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,')
            if (price.indexOf('.') > -1) {
                varSplit = price.toString().split('.');
                varSplit[0] = varSplit[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
                varSplit[1] = varSplit[1].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
                $scope.item.price = varSplit.join('.');
            }
        }
  }
```

The solution I'm looking for would be something along these lines:

```
<input ng-model="item.price" ng-change="addCommas(item.price)"/>

$scope.addCommas = function(x) {
  if (x) {
    // functions here, only working with 'x', not with item or price.
    return x
  }
}
```

Like, for example, the following:

```
function double(x) {
  return x * 2
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good use-case for your first directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to convert your function into directive:

```
app.directive('addCommas', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
          'ngModel': '='
      },
      link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.$watch('ngModel',function() {
          var value = $scope.ngModel.toString();
          //console.log(value)
          if (value){
            value = value.replace(/,/g, '')
            $scope.ngModel = value.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,')
            if (value.indexOf('.') > -1) {
              varSplit = value.toString().split('.');
              varSplit[0] = varSplit[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
              varSplit[1] = varSplit[1].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
              $scope.ngModel = varSplit.join('.');
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

And HTML:

```
 <input type="text" name='' ng-model='item.price' add-commas/>
```

The directive "binds" to the input's `ng-model`, watches for changes and applies the transformation.

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fZ756sDAMi2rapwdXSX7?p=preview).

Two more versions: [directive which binds to item with price property](http://plnkr.co/edit/3quZpQ1AIp78kv4wupvm) and [stand-alone directive with own template](http://plnkr.co/edit/xgpd6CbwG3gNdLXSUJQS?p=preview).

Comment: your directive still refers to item, I'm looking for a solution without the explicit item

Comment: @murid do you mean something like a completely stand-alone directive? Or do you want to be able to pass the value from controller to this directive and then get this value back? If you want to have it both in controller and directive, you still need to have some common "item", check also this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xgpd6CbwG3gNdLXSUJQS?p=preview), it is a stand-alone directive with two-way communication.

Comment: Still not quite there, now you're using a template. I've edited the original post with a comment at the bottom to make it clearer.

Comment: @murid OK, I think I got what you want, check the updated answer and new [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fZ756sDAMi2rapwdXSX7?p=preview). Now directive just binds to input's `ng-model` and transforms the value, so you can use it the same way for any input.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fully functioning directive you can model after.

Feel free to modify this for your own use but it basically accomplishes what you want and has some other nice features.

Directive:

```
angular.module('maskModule').directive('maskTextbox', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:'templates/mask-textbox.html',
        scope: {
            maskDisplayModel: '=?',
            maskModel: '=?',
            maskType: '@',
            maskCurrency: '@',
            placeHolder: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.maskDisplayModel = "";
            if (!scope.maskCurrency)
                scope.maskCurrency = "$";
            var t;
            scope.timer = 1;

            if (!scope.placeHolder && scope.maskType == "phone") {
                scope.placeHolder = "Phone..."
            }

            if (!scope.placeHolder && scope.maskType == "currency") {
                scope.placeHolder = "Amount..."
            }

            if (!scope.placeHolder && (scope.maskType == "number" || scope.maskType == "decimal" || scope.maskType == "alpha")) {
                scope.placeHolder = "Type here..."
            }

            scope.countdown = function () {
                if (scope.timer == 0) {
                    scope.changeAction()
                } else {
                    scope.timer -= 1;
                    t = setTimeout(function () {
                        scope.countdown();
                    }, 750);
                }
            };

            scope.resetTimer = function () {
                scope.timer = 1;
                clearTimeout(t);
                scope.countdown();
            };

            scope.changeAction = function () {
                if (scope.maskType == "number") {
                    scope.maskModel = scope.maskDisplayModel.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                    scope.maskDisplayModel = scope.maskDisplayModel.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                }
                if (scope.maskType == "decimal") {
                    scope.maskModel = scope.maskDisplayModel.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
                    scope.maskDisplayModel = scope.maskDisplayModel.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
                }
                if (scope.maskType == "phone") {
                    scope.maskModel = scope.maskDisplayModel.replace(/[^0-9-()]/g, '');
                    scope.maskDisplayModel = scope.maskDisplayModel.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                    scope.maskDisplayModel = $filter("tel")(scope.maskDisplayModel)
                }
                if (scope.maskType == "alpha") {
                    scope.maskModel = scope.maskDisplayModel.replace(/[^A-maska-mask]/g, '');
                    scope.maskDisplayModel = scope.maskDisplayModel.replace(/[^A-maska-mask]/g, '');
                }
                if (scope.maskType == "currency") {
                    scope.maskModel = scope.maskDisplayModel.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
                    scope.maskDisplayModel = scope.maskDisplayModel.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
                    scope.maskDisplayModel = $filter("currency")(scope.maskDisplayModel, scope.maskCurrency)
                }
            };

            scope.initiate = function () {
                if (scope.maskType == "number") {
                    scope.maskModel = scope.maskModel.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                    scope.maskDisplayModel = scope.maskModel.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                }
                if (scope.maskType == "decimal") {
                    scope.maskModel = scope.maskModel.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
                    scope.maskDisplayModel = scope.maskModel.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
                }
                if (scope.maskType == "phone") {
                    scope.maskModel = scope.maskModel.replace(/[^0-9-()]/g, '');
                    scope.maskDisplayModel = $filter("tel")(scope.maskModel);
                }
                if (scope.maskType == "alpha") {
                    scope.maskModel = scope.maskModel.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, '');
                    scope.maskDisplayModel = scope.maskModel.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, '');
                }
                if (scope.maskType == "currency") {
                    scope.maskModel = scope.maskModel.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
                    scope.maskDisplayModel = $filter("currency")(scope.maskModel, scope.maskCurrency, 2);
                }

            };

            scope.initiate();
        }
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="maskDisplayModel" ng-blur="changeAction()" placeholder="{{placeHolder}}"/>
```

HTML referencing directive:

```
<mask-textbox mask-model="myText" mask-type="phone"></mask-textbox>
```